# A greedy solution for a matrix rearrangment

Tags: algorithm

I am working on something which I feel an NP-hard problem. So, I am not looking for the optimal solution but I am looking for a better heuristics. An integer input matrix (matrix A in the following example) is given as input and I have to produce an integer output matrix (matrix B in the following example) whose number of rows are smaller than the input matrix and should obey the following two conditions:

1) Each column of the output matrix should contain integers in the same order as they appear in the input matrix. (In the example below, first column of the matrix A and matrix B have the same integers 1,3 in the same order.)

2) Same integers must not appear in the same row (In the example below, first row of the matrix B contains the integers 1,3 and 2 which are different from each other.)

Note that the input matrix always obey the 2nd condition.

What a greedy algorithm looks like to solve this problem?

Example:

[image]

In this example the output matrix 'Matrix B' contains all the integers as they appear in the input matrix 'Matrix A" but the output matrix has 5 rows and the input matrix has 6 rows. So, the output 'Matrix B' is a valid solution of the input 'Matrix A'.

Comment: Is Matrix A a valid solution to the input Matrix A? Or is it possible that there will be an unsolvable problem?

Comment: Could this be Job Shop Scheduling? This is described, for instance, in the first few paragraphs of http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.159.1650&rep=rep1&type=pdf. If so, there is an awful lot of stuff out there you could read - a web search on job shop scheduling finds a lot of stuff, and the document in the link above talks about "a huge amount of literature" (The job shop scheduling problem: Conventional and new solution techniques, by Blazewicz, Domschke, and Pesch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would produce the output one row at a time. When working out what to put in the row I would consider the next number from each input column, starting from the input column which has the most numbers yet to be placed, and considering the columns in decreasing order of numbers yet to be placed. Where a column can put a number in the current output row when its turn comes up it should do so.

You could extend this to a branch and bound solution to find the exact best answer. Recursively try all possible rows at each stage, except when you can see that the current row cannot possibly improve on the best answer so far. You know that if you have a column with k entries yet to be placed, in the best possible case you will need at least k more rows.

In practice I would expect that this will be too expensive to be practical, so you will need to ignore some possible rows which you cannot rule out, and so cannot guarantee to find the best answer. You could try using a heuristic search such as Limited Discrepancy search.

Another non-exact speedup is to multiply the estimate for the number of rows that the best possible answer derived from a partial solution will require by some factor F > 1. This will allow you to rule out some solutions earlier than branch and bound. The answer you find can be no more than F times more expensive than the best possible answer, because you only discard possibilities that cannot improve on the current answer by more than a factor of F.

Answer (score 0):

A greedy solution to this problem would involve placing the numbers column by column, top down, as they appear.

Pseudocode:

```
For each column c in A:
   r = 0 // row index of next element in A
   nextRow = 0 // row index of next element to be placed in B
   while r < A.NumRows()
      while r < A.NumRows() && A[r, c] is null:
         r++ // increment row to check in A
      if r < A.NumRows() // we found a non-null entry in A
         while nextRow < A.NumRows() && ~CheckConstraints(A[r,c], B[nextRow, c]):
            nextRow++ // increment output row in B
         if 'nextRow' >= A.NumRows()
            return unsolvable // couldn't find valid position in B
         B[nextRow, c] = v // successfully found position in B
          ++nextRow  // increment output row in B
```

If there are no conflicts you end up "packing" B as tightly as possible. Otherwise you greedily search for the next non-conflicting row position in `B`. If none can be found, the problem is unsolvable.

The helper function `CheckConstraints` checks backwards in columns for the same row value in `B` to ensure the same value hasn't already been placed in a row.

If the problem statement is relaxed such that the output row count in B is <= the row count in A, then if we are unable to pack B any tighter, then we can return A as a solution.